# Making a bot with PRAW. It seems to ignore some people?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

my first post here. If you check out /r/EDH right now you'll see my bot on the front page. The idea is that when you type ?edhbot [name of a card]? it gives you links to relevant pages on edhrec.com.

For some reason however it seems to ignore some people and my bot isn't reporting any rate limit issues. They're not getting the wakeword wrong, so I really can't work out what they're doing wrong? Here's my code for reference:

```
  #imported modules
  import praw
  import string

  #functions
  def main():
        #API login
        #I have no idea what I can't show so I redacted most lol
        reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="REDACTED",
                             client_secret = "REDACTED",
                             user_agent = "a bot for my epq, by aggressivechairs",
                             username = "EPQ_MTG_BOT",
                             password = "REDACTED")
        subreddit = reddit.subreddit("all")
        wakeword = "?edhbot "

        for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
              if wakewordCheck(comment, wakeword): reply = generateComment(comment)

  #Checks comment to see if it contains the wake word for the bot
  def wakewordCheck(comment, wakeword):
        if wakeword in comment.body: return(True)
        else: return(False)

  #Generates the link extension
  def linkGenerator(inString):
        startPoint = inString.index("?edhbot ")
        inString = inString.lower()
        outString = ""
        for i in range(startPoint+8, len(inString)):
              if inString[i] == "?":
                    break
              elif inString[i] in string.punctuation:
                    continue
              elif inString[i] in string.whitespace:
                    outString += "-"
                    continue
              outString += inString[i]
        return(outString)



  #Generates the text that will be used in the bot's reply
  def generateComment(comment):
        try:
              normalisedLink = linkGenerator(comment.body)
              commentReply = "[EDHRec page for the commander](https://edhrec.com/commanders/"+normalisedLink+") \n\n [EDHREC page for that as a card](https://edhrec.com/cards/"+normalisedLink+")"
              comment.reply(commentReply)
              print("I did it with " + comment.body)
        except Exception as e: print(e)            

  if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

So yeah, when you use type ?edhbot it either reads until the end of the comment or until it encounters a new question mark. If you check out this thread though you can see that it just elects to ignore some people. https://www.reddit.com/r/EDH/comments/9ec677/im_a_new_bot_made_just_for_this_sub/?sort=new

What do you suggest? I can't work out what's going wrong :/ Oh and if you spot any bad coding practice feel free to tell me! I want to improve haha